# Does CVE-2016-10229 have a USN

Tags: kernel, security

Hey at work we use USN's to track various vulnerabilities and prioritize them for review. We noticed this USN come out on [Ubuntu's CVE site](https://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-security/cve/2016/CVE-2016-10229.html) but haven't seen the associated USN show up [on the regular feed](https://www.ubuntu.com/usn/).

Given that the patch was release for this a long time ago, it would be nice to have a USN released so that we can not have to make a custom note in our system for tracking patched Ubuntu vulns.

Can this be done?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but as near as I can tell this CVE does not exist or does not affect any of the [currently supported](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases) releases of Ubuntu

Comment: The vuln still affects 14.04 LTS system albeit those with older kernels installed. Patches have been released a while ago but it's super nice to point to the USN when tracking.

Especially the version table, makes it simple to "sell an action" upwards to management.

Comment: Isn't a USN a [Microsoft Active Directory update numbering system](http://searchwindowsserver.techtarget.com/definition/update-sequence-number-USN) and so off-topic here? Sorry, I've got nothing for you.

Comment: https://www.ubuntu.com/usn/ Ubuntu Security Notice

Comment: Unless I'm completely off base, Ubuntu security notices that affect the current supported releases of Ubuntu can be found [here](https://www.ubuntu.com/usn/)  Sorry I couldn't be of more help.

Comment: Indeed. and this CVE affects a current supported release of Ubuntu.  Specifically Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. Note the table titled simply linux (http://imgur.com/a/HSRmn). According to the release table on the wiki it's supported unit April of 2019.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58548/discussion-between-christopher-and-elder-geek).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The very first line of the USN page says:

> These are the Ubuntu security notices that affect the current
>   supported releases of Ubuntu.

Note: **currently supported**. The CVE tracker page notes that none of the currently supported releases are affected:

- 12.04 under ESM is, but I'd think *that* would have a separate channel for such notices
- And for 14.04, it mostly says: "ignored (end-of-life)"

While it'd be a nice-to-have, that should be a feature request reported to Ubuntu, and Ask Ubuntu is not the place for that.

Comment: But 14.04 LTS is suppose to be [supported until 2019](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases) and you see the 3.13.x line of kernel packages still receiving notifications when they get patched. Most recently [USN-3264-1](https://www.ubuntu.com/usn/usn-3264-1/) describes a patch for [CVE-2017-5986](http://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-security/cve/2017/CVE-2017-5986.html) available for the same line of packages.

When did 14.04.1 LTS become unsupported?

Comment: @Christopher it says the 3.13 kernel of 14.04 is not affected (DNE), and for HWE kernels, see https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack#Kernel.2FSupport.A14.04.x_Ubuntu_Kernel_Support

Comment: It has this line : "Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (Trusty Tahr): | released (3.13.0-79.123) " under the table "linux" Indicating it is affected.

Comment: @Christopher no, that just means it was affected and fixed, but not necessarily as part of any action for this CVE. If you check the changelog, the CVEs marked as fixed by that version don't include this CVE, so it was fixed as a side-effect in February 2016, long before this CVE was created. So, at the time the CVE was created, the 3.13 kernel in 14.04 had long since become unaffected.

Comment: I'm aware that the fixed version was released a long time ago but is that the official position? That if a CVE is for a packaged version of software more than X releases old It doesn't get a USN? I can live with that and it makes sense. However as we have older systems it's easier to point to a USN (well respected and straight forward with it's remediation steps in the org) as a reason for needing to reboot a long lived system.

Comment: @Christopher if you want an "official" word on the matter, I'm afraid your posting on the wrong site. You'd be better of filing a bug or posting on the appropriate mailing list where the devs can respond directly. All I can say is that I have usually only seen USNs when fixes were being released.